# Can I conditionally change which function I'm calling?

Tags: python

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the words to search that would give me the answer I'm looking for.

I'm writing a script that contains a helper function, which, in turn, can call one of several functions which all take the same parameters. In this helper function, I end up having strings of this:

```
if funcName="func1":
  func1(p1, p2, p3)
elif funcName="func2":
  func2(p1, p2, p3)
elif funcName="func3":
  func3(p1, p2, p3)
...
```

I know that I could use another helper function that would also take the funcName string and distribute it to the appropriate function, but is there a better way to do it? What my brain wants to do is this:

```
funcName(p1, p2, p3)
```

That way I could call an arbitrary function name if I want to. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using a `dict` mapping names to functions:

```
funcs = dict(
    func1=func1,
    func2=func2,
    func3=func3
)

funcs[funcName](p1, p2, p3)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I wanted exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you put the functions inside an object like so:

```
var funcs = 
{
    f1: function() {},
    f2: function() {},
    f3: function() {}
}
```

You can do `funcs['f1']()` for example.

Comment: What, what. This is python. Sorry!

Comment: The answer is correct in principle, but the OP is asking about Python, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can call them within the `locals` or `globals` dict:

```
locals()[funcName](p1, p2, p3)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = lambda x: x+1
>>> locals()['a'](2)
3
```

As commented below you may check if they are within expected:

```
if funcName in ["func1", "func2", "func3"]:
    locals()[funcName](p1, p2, p3)
```

Comment: Beware that if `funcName` comes from malicious user, this way you let him access *all* functions in the scope.